# Declare a struct in a function

Tags: c++, sdl2

I am creating a game that sometimes crashes and i am asking if this could be the cause.
Take this code:

```
struct SDL_FloatRect
{
    float x, y;
    float w, h;
};

void random_func()
{
    SDL_FloatRect rect;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    while(1)
    {
        ...
        random_func();
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see.. there is a rect created every frame.
I sometimes create them for satisfying some functions parameters (for example a function parameter is of type SDL_Rect but i have only x and y).
I don't know if this causes memory leak
Or something like..
(But i know that at the end of a function, variables get destroyed)
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE! Although you use a library typically used in video games, this question is more about c++ than it's application in gamedev. These questions should be asked on SO.

Comment: Also please note that when a question has an answer, you accept the relevant answer, we don't edit the question with the solution.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt sorry i forgot to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not leak because the rect memory is allocated on stack (in opposite to heap allocation) so it is deallocated when the random_func returns.

The information you have provided is not enough to diagnose the crash. A crash dump or some more code would be helpful.

Comment: My code is about 6000 lines and debugger don't tell me anything about the position of the error.. i see it's Segmentation Fault, and i am trying to fix it. (Thanks for your reply, it was helpful)

Comment: You can try using AddressSanitizer to find the root cause of the crash: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer